# Strange characters after posting text in eclipse jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, encoding

After i post some text in my jsp it showed a warning about enconding. I still paste the text but now it shows like this and I can't undo.

[image: Page]

Comment: Could you check in Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace which encodes do you use?

Comment: It looks like UTF(-16) being interpreted as single-byte encoding (some ISO-Latin).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (generally, pictures of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) are useless).